# Including Running JUnit Tests as part of Jenkins Config

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins to include a Post Build step to run JUnit tests and am getting an error:

The Jenkins step itself shows an issue:

```
target/surefire-reports/*.xml
‘target/surefire-reports/*.xml’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘*.xml’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?
```

This isn't surprising because I don't have a surefire-reports sub folder under targets and I have no idea what I have to do to generate the xml report. I am new to Java, Maven, Eclipse, Linux - everything - and working alone.

My main question is:

**Does this configuration suggest that I should be necessarily looking into using ANT integration?** I don't even know what acronyms I should be reading about yet and I was hoping for some direction to cut the curve.

I saw internal instructions for setting up this post build step but now I need to know what to do to make it work.

Thanks

```
INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ FDE ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.445 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-15T10:59:18-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/38M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
Recording test results
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Checking for post-build
Performing post-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
Overriding default server settings, creating our own session
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
Adding developers
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
Setting In-Reply-To since last build was not successful
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: John.Doe@MyCom.com
Changing BUILD_ID variable (job build time) with the date pattern MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a.
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

Comment: Have you run the build at least once first for Jenkins to generate the files?  If not, and you are sure that's where the JUnit output file will be then it should be OK

Answer (score 1):

There's an Ant task for generating JUnit reports.  Add `<junitreport>` task to your Ant build and make it dependent on the `<junit>` task.

Comment: It looks like target/surefire-reports/*.xml is associated with using MAVEN rather than ANT.